# Create a maven plugin that would copy a set of folders and files

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am very new to Maven Plugins. Hence this silly question(I guess). I want to create a Maven plugin that would have a goal to copy a folder and file( that resides within the maven plugin project) to the workspace of the project that uses this maven plugin. Is that something which is possible I am expecting something not possible using a Maven plugin.

Comment: First of all, could you please explain what you want to with such a hypothetical plugin? It is likely that we find a more elegant and direct solution to your original problem.

Comment: As a developer of the plugin, I would provide some boiler-plate code when the developer compiles it in his workspace. This will help the developer to write some code on top of the boiler plat code that would generate in his workspace.

Comment: For this, you use maven archetypes.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to have resources in my Maven Plugin Project. Thinking, how can I extract the files from the resources folder of the plugin(.jar!/resources/x.txt), when the plugin is executed in a different workspace.

Comment: Have you looked into Maven Archetypes? They are the meant to be used to create sample project structures.